# Why is this code doesn't have a return statement?

Tags: javascript

JS documentations shows the language does have the 'return' statement
So why is this word not is this code?
This is from the example app of the Wikitude JS SDK for Android

```
var World = {

     markerDrawable_idle: null,

     locationChanged: function locationChangedFn(lat, lon, alt, acc) {

        World.markerDrawable_idle = new AR.ImageResource("assets/marker_idle.png");

        var marker = new AR.ImageDrawable(World.markerDrawable_idle, 2.5, {
            zOrder: 0,
            opacity: 1.0
        });

        var markerLocation = new AR.GeoLocation(31.260911, 34.801737, 302.5);

        var markerObject1 = new AR.GeoObject(markerLocation, {
            drawables: {
                cam: [marker]
            }
        }); 
    },
};
AR.context.onLocationChanged = World.locationChanged;
```

What is the use of locationChanged function if it doesn't return anything?

Comment: Why would it need to return something? Functions *can*, but they aren't *required to*.

Comment: So how does their internal (var) objects are used? i work mainly with Java, so i guess for me var is same as private

Comment: Ok i got it. the assignment operator assigns the CODE of the function and not the result of the funciton.

Comment: That’s correct. You need parentheses to call the function (and, presumably, pass the arguments).

Comment: Thank you, the only problem i have is that this function doesnt alter anything outside of it nor does it print to screen (or these sort of things). it merely creating objects and particularly PRIVATE obects (defined with var). so what use does this have? how could it be good for somthing?

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, functions *can* return something, but they're not required to. If they don't, then `undefined` is returned by default. Notice that not all control paths need return a value, though having cases where some paths do and some don't is almost surely a bug.

In C/C++/Java/C#, such functions would return `void`, for example.

Comment: Thank you, the only problem i have is that this function doesnt alter anything outside of it nor does it print to screen (or these sort of things). it merely creating objects and particularly PRIVATE obects (defined with var). so what use does this have? how could it be good for somthing?